# Regular expression match HTML Tag Pattern for PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I have an HTML string and want to extract content inside a particular tag `<selection>`.

Example:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply <selection alt="dummy" name="dummy">dummy</selection > text the printing and typesetting <selection alt="industry" name="industry">industry</selection>. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's <selection alt="standard" name="standard">standard</selection>dummy text ever since the 1500s.
```

In the above HTML string I need to extract text inside `selection` tags, but all tags have different attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/<selection.*?">(.*?)<\/selection.*?>/is',$sourcestring,$matches);
```

The `$matches` is your result in the form of array.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this:

```
/<selection[^>]*>([^<]*)/g
```

http://regex101.com/r/pS3sM0/1

To allow tags between `<selection>...</selection>`:

```
/<selection[^>]*>(.*?)(?:<\/selection)/g
```

Comment: And what happens if name attribute contains `>>><<<`?